# Azure AD Differential query - Detect change in Directory role assignment for a user

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using differential query (AzureAD graph API) to detect changes in Azure AD from the last sync. I am getting all users, group memberships, manager changes. Only missing information is Directory Role assignment (e.g Billing administrator, SharePoint administrator etc).
How can I detect a change in roles of any user?

`API - https://graph.windows.net/{org}/directoryObjects?api-version=1.5&deltaLink=xxxxxttttxxxxxxxx`

Answer (score 0):

First, if you have enabled those Directory Roles, you can use AAD Graph API [operations on directory roles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/directoryroles-operations#GetDirectoryRoleMembers) to list  members of those roles.

```
GET https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/directoryRoles/{object_id}/$links/members?api-version=1.6
```

But, This API can also list service principals which assigned this role.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am doing for the initial sync. But, I am looking for a way to get the delta later on, as I don't want to do full sync all the time. I store 'deltaLink' and then query AzureAD to get whatever changes happened after my last sync.